# Parameter pass from php script to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, parameters

```
html
<?php $test="00010387";
<a href="javascript:browsePricebySKU(<?php echo '$test';?>);"></a>

javascript
<script>
function browsePricebySKU(test){
alert(test);}
</script>
```

the output is different with the parameter. Please help me.

Comment: Your example is kind of non-explanatory. If the PHP syntax were correct, it would work. What else have you tried to analyze your issue? And please refrain from using the penetrant "please help me" with all your questions.

Comment: I see you are new user: do you know that you should "accept" one of the answers if it correctly answers your question? For this you click on the bird icon to the left of the answer, below the digit between two triangles. You can also click the triangles if you like an answer (up triangle) or dislike (down triangle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**php code**

```
<?php $test="00010387"; ?>

<a href="javascript:browsePricebySKU('<?php echo $test;?>');"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">

     function browsePricebySKU(test){

          alert(test);
      }
</script>
```

**Single quotes will not be Escape, It will output $test as a string, not the value of the $test variable;**

Answer (score 1):

```
html
<?php $test="00010387";?>
<a href="javascript:browsePricebySKU('<?php echo $test;?>');"></a>
```

(close php before starting html)

or

```
html
<?php $test="00010387";
echo "<a href=\"javascript:browsePricebySKU('$test');\"></a>";
```

Comment: Yep because 00010387 is the same as 10387 (as a number), whereas if you add single quotes around it, it should identify itself as a string.

Comment: if i use single quotes, the output is $test and not the data. I changed it to double quotes and it works. thanks

Comment: I corrected the answer -- the quotes around $test in the first part were there by a mistake.